# Is it possible to compile tensorflow in Mac?

Tags: tensorflow

So I started to build tensorflow in Mac and the thing is that it doesn't seem possible to build tensorflow in Mac OS platform.

After following instructions in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), I get this package directory.

[image: directory hierarchy]

It seems like the build settings for bazel is only for linux distro. The reason why I thought so is because there is a .so file in package directory that is needed to be linked after importing tensorflow using python binary.

This is the result I get after importing tensorflow using python.

[image: terminal]

Is there any other way I can build tensorflow on Mac OS?

Comment: Did you run the `./configure` script? or run `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Comment: @onurgüngör Is it important to use --config=opt flag on building tensorflow?

Comment: Yes, probably, but not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are no options but to install tensorflow with **pip**. So I just created a new virtual machine and installed **ubuntu 16.04** to use it as my docker host. By doing so, I can create a new docker container which can now link and execute the linux library.